# Does anyone else get empty search results when using Facebook Graph API Public Search?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Could someone do me a flavour and let me know if you also get back an empty json array when you click on the sample user search url on the Facebook Graph Api docs page.

Here is the page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

It is in the search section. the people link.

Here is  the link I am clicking and all other search links return data except the user search.

[image: Facebook Screenshot]

This is what I get back

[image: Facebook Results]

My question is do other people have this problem as well or is it just me.

Comment: you mean this? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

Comment: no i mean https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=***MY ACCESS TOKEN ***  almost always returns an empty json array

Comment: could you please elaborate your question a lot more. i am sure you are missing something in your api call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that it has to do with the way Facebook filters by privacy after they've selected your results. Meaning graph asks for (X) results, Facebook finds (X) results that match your search, then removes those who have it in their privacy options not me be searched, and then after filtering returns what's left. This is explained on Facebook's dev blog: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

See the following answer for clearer details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11848002/624590

That said, it could be something else - I've noticed it's been getting especially bad in recent weeks; fewer and fewer results seem to be returned.

Comment: You can also try with more specific names, but there's a good chance it's a coincidence and merely allowing the search to jump over a lot of privacy-stricken accounts (e.g. "greg star" seems to work, at the time of writing this response).

Comment: Man that's annoying, thanks for the tip, other question you linked to answered why its happening.

Comment: Glad I could help - it's been affecting me as well. It's a pretty frustrating model they've got set up, hopefully in the future search becomes slightly more useful (like it was just weeks ago).

Comment: When I first started using it there was no issue, "Jack" would return plenty of results. Now it is really random what will return anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

We've been getting empty results for type=post for periods of 1-2 hours for the past few days. I'm sure it's related to something on their end, check out my bug post here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/456910301017301?browse=search_509b0461dc68c0151458645